# Looking for tips to build "TestMaker" (Questions and Responses) application with Evaluation Engine

Tags: c#, business-logic, business-rules

I'm working on a new project.
My best analogy would be a psychological evaluation test maker.

**Aspect #1.**
The end-business-user needs to create test questions.  With question types.  And possible responses to the questions when applicable.

Examples:

```
1.  Do you have red hair?  (T/F)

2.  What is your favorite color?  (Single Response/Multiple Choice)
    (Possible Responses: Red, Yellow, Black, White)

3.  What size shoe do you wear (rounded to next highest size)?  (Integer)

4.  How much money do you have on you right now?  (Dollar Amount (decimal))
```

So I need to be able to create questions, their question type, and for some of the questions, possible answers.

Here:

Number 1 is a know type of "True or False".

Number 2 is a know type of "Single Response/Multiple Choice" AND the end-business-user will create the possible responses.

Number 3 is a known type of "Integer".  The end-user (person taking the evaluation) can basically put in any integer value.

Number 4 is a known type of "Decimal".  Same thing as Integer.

**Aspect #2.**
The end-business-user needs to evaluate the person's responses.  And assign some scalar value to a set of responses.

Example:

If someone responded:

```
1.  T
2.  Red
3.  >=8
4.  (Not considered for this situation)
```

Some psychiatrist-expert figures out that if someone answered with the above responses, that you are a 85% more at risk for depression than the normal.  (Where 85% is a number the end-business-user (psychiatrist) can enter as a parameter.

So Aspect #2 is running through someone's responses, and determining a result.

The "response grid" would have to be setup so that it will go through (some or all) the possibilities in a priority ranking order, and then after all conditions are met (on a single row), exit out with the result.

Like this:

```
(1.) T     (2.) Red       (3.) >=8    ... Result = 85%
(1.) T     (2.) Yellow    (3.) >=8    ... Result = 70%
(1.) F     (2.) Red       (3.) >=8    ... Result = 50%
(1.) F     (2.) Yellow    (3.) >=8    ... Result = 40%
```

Once a match is found, you exit with the percentage.  If you don't find a match, you go to the next rule.

Also, running with this psych evaluation mock example, I don't need to define every permutation. A lot of questions of psych evaluations are not actually used, they are just "fluff".  So in my grid above, I have purposely left out question #4.  It has no bearing on the results.

There can also be a "Did this person take this seriously?" evaluation grid:

```
(3.) >=20    (4.) >=$1,000    ... Result = False
```

(The possibility of having a shoe size >= 20 and having big dollars in your pocket is very low, thus you probably did not take the psych test seriously.)

If no rule is found, (in my real application, not this mock up), I would throw an exception or just not care.  I would not need a default or fall-through rule.
In the above, Red and Yellow are "worrisome" favorite colors.  If your favorite color is black or white, it has no bearing upon your depression risk factor.

I have used Business Rule Engines in the past.  (InRule for example).
They are very expensive, and it is not in the budget.

BizTalk Business Rules Framework is a possibility.  Not de$irable, but possible.

My issue with any Rules-Engine is that the "vocabulary" (I have limited experience with business rules engines, mind you) is based off of objects, with static properties.

```
public class Employee
{
        public string LastName
        { get; set; }

        public DateTime HireDate
        { get; set; }

        public decimal AnnualSalary
        { get; set; }

        public void AdjustSalary(int percentage)
        {
            this.AdjustSalary= this.AdjustSalary + (this.AdjustSalary * percentage);
        }

}
```

This would be easy to create business rules.

```
If 
        the (Employee's HireDate) is before (10 years ago) 

then 
        (Increase Their Salary) By (5) Percent.)

else
        (Increase Their Salary) By (3) Percent.)
```

But in my situation, the Test is composed of (dynamic) Questions and (dynamic) Responses, not predetermined properties.

So I guess I'm looking for some ideas to investigate on how to pull this off.

I know I can build a "TestMaker" application fairly quickly.

The biggest issue is integrating the Questions and (Possible Responses) into "evaluating rules".

Thanks for any tips.

Technologies:
DotNet 4.0 Framework
Sql Server 2008 Backend Database
VS2010 Pro, C#

Comment: This is probably by far the longest question I've seen on Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Posts
.OrderByDescending( p => p.Body.Length)
.Where (p => p.PostTypeId == 1)
.Take(10)
http://coderjournal.com/2010/06/using-linqpad-to-query-stack-overflow/
Maybe! :)  You can check it out if you're really really bored.

Comment: Do you prefer the result being determined using SQL queries or using plain C#?

Comment: C# Business Logic.  SQL is for CRUD operations, IMHO.  I try to write as little as possible business logic in the TSQL.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a small application, i.e 10s of users as opposed to 1000s, and its not business critical, then I would recommend Excel.

The advantages are, most business users are very familiar with excel and most probably have it on their machines. Basically you ship an Excel Workbook to your business users. They would enter the questions, the Type (Decimal, True False etc.). Click a button which triggers an excel macro. This could generate an XML configuration file or put the questions into SQL. Your application just reads it, displays it and collects responses as usual.

The main advantage of Excel comes in Aspect #2, the dynamic user chosen business rules. In another sheet of the same Excel document, the end business user can specify as many of the permutations of the responses/questions as they feel like. Excel users are very familiar with inputting simple formulas like =If(A1 > 20 && A2 <50) etc. Again the user pushes a button and generates either a configuration file or input the data into SQL server.

In your application you iterate through the Rules table and apply it to the responses.

Given the number of users/surveys etc. This simple solution would be much more simpler than biztalk or a full on customs rules engine. Biztalk would be good if you need to talk to multiple system, integrate their data, enforce rules, create work flow etc. Most of the other rules engines are also geared towards really big, complex rule system. The complexity in this rule systems, isn't just the number of rules or permutations, it is mostly having to talk to multiple system or "End dating" certain rules or putting in rules for future kick off dates etc.

In your case an Excel based or a similar datagrid on a webpage system would work fine. Unless of course you are doing a project for Gartner or some other global data survey firm or a major government statistical organisation. In that case I would suggest Biztalk or other commercial rules engines.

In your case, its SQL tables with Questions, Answer Types, Rules To Apply. Input is made user friendly via Excel or "Excel in the web" via a datagrid and then just iterate through the rules and apply them to the response table.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but an Excel solution isn't feasible.  //then just iterate through the rules and apply them to the response table//  That is the sticking point.  Which is the "how" to do this, not the "what to do".  As I alluded, business rules engines are built upon static properties of objects.  Thank you for the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use a business rule engine for this problem?

As far as I understand it, the usecase for a BRE is

- Mostly static execution flow
- Some decisions do change often

In your usecase, the whole system (Q/A-flow and evaluation) are dynamic, so IMHO a simple domain specific language for the whole system would be a better solution.

---

You might want to take some inspiration from [testMaker](http://www.global-assess.rwth-aachen.de/testmaker-wiki/en/index.php/Main_Page) - a web based software exactly for this workflow. (Disclaimer: I contributed a bit to this project.) Its scoring rules are quite basic, so this might not help you that much. It was designed to export data to SPSS and build reports from there...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are modeling a database suitable for hierarchical objects [This article would help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_database_model)

create table for test
create tables for questions, with columns question, testid, questiontype
create tables for answers, answer id,question id, answer and istrue columns
answers belong to questions
one question can have many answer

create table for user or employee
create table for user answers, answer id, selected answer

evaluation (use object variables for boolean-integer coverage, use try catch before using function for high exception coverage.):

```
function(questiontype,answer,useranswer)
switch(questiontype) //condition can be truefalse, biggerthan,smallerthan, equals
{
case: "biggerthan": if(useranswer>answer) return true else return false;
case "truefalse": if(useranswer==answer) return true else return false
case "equals": if(useranswer==answer) return true else return false
}
```

get output as a data dictionary and post here please.
without a data schema the help you get will be limited.